# Is it possible to interact with the browser devtools with selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

For example if I am using Youtube on google chrome, and I want to extract my youtube device ID from local storage in devtools. Is it possible to do so in selenium?

E.g. The key in the application local storage is "yt-remote-device-id" and I want to extract '22acf168-869b-4345-b935-1bd0de15c5ff' out of the value of '{"data":"22acf168-869b-4345-b935-1bd0de15c5ff","expiration":1688591002039,"creation":1657055002039}' will this be possible?

I'm using selenium webdriver with python

Answer (score 2):

`Selenium` provides the `execute_script()` method, which allows you to execute JavaScript code within the context of the current page.

Updated (thx to @pguardiario):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")

# Execute JavaScript code to retrieve the device ID from local storage and parse it as JSON
device_id = driver.execute_script('return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("yt-remote-device-id")).data')

print(device_id)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

xFranco almost had it...

```
device_id = driver.execute_script("""
  return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("yt-remote-device-id")).data
""")
```